# Xcode - (ionic app) - build AND archive?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-cli

This is probably a dumb question... I just want to make sure I am not doubling up here. Once I am done with my ionic code, I run `ionic build --release` from the command line. Then, in Xcode I run clean, then build, then archive.

Question - if I am archiving do I need to run build first?  It almost looks like Xcode is building the project again as part of the archiving process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your process is good.  But, you're right, you don't need to build first, you can archive directly.